# Problema en onClickListener con Button en Fragment para mostrar datos en Activity que contiene el Fragment

Tags: android-fragment, fragment, click, android-context

soy novato novato en Android y estoy haciendo un proyecto el cual contiene:

ActiviyMain.class
ActivityMain.Layout
Fragment.Class
Fragment.layout

Resulta que tengo un botón en el Fragment.layout que está dentro del layout ActivityMain, dicho botón al presionarlo se debe mostrar información en el ActivityMain, pero al hacerlo me tira un error que adjunto en la imagen. Quito la línea del button.onClickListener y se ejecuta todo bien.[image: Este es el error que me lanza al hacer Debug en la línea del problema]

Comment: Has hecho el findViewId del button ? Adjunta algo más de código, el Create y el método del button si puedes.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que ocurre es que estás definiendo el evento OnClick en objeto button que todavía no tiene la referencia al objeto de la vista.

Asegurate de buscar previamente el botón en la vista:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // OnClick;
        }

    });
```